# ASP.NET MVC 4 in ASP.NET Webform project with themes

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, themes

I am currently adding ASP.Net MVC 4 content in an large existing ASP.Net WebForm application because my client want to develop his new pages with MVC4 without having to remake the existing pages.
I know this subject has already been covered elsewhere on stackoverflow and it works.
Here is the article I am following to do this: http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

My problem is that the existing project works with the App_themes folder to have different themes/skins because the same web site is targeted to different people.

Question: **How do I keep the ASP.Net Webform theme system working and how do I handle this same functionality in the new MVC 4 pages?**

Thanks a lot fellow .NET devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A theme is nothing more than skin files ( html markup fragments, CSS files and images by default themes are located in APP_THEMES if it does not exist, you should create it. Each theme should be in its own folder.

Themes are located by asp.net by defining the following section in your web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <pages theme="ThemeName" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This should allow the existing asp.net (non-mvc) files to use the theme correctly.

The problem will be with the format of the skin files, the markup is in asp.net web forms format. If the razor engine is used for mvc, the skins will not be comparable.

Two choices:

- don't use the razor engine for markup
- create a copy of the theme with razor formatted skins

For more about themes see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh(v=vs.100).aspx